# open source convert for .b3d model file

Tags: graphics, 3d

Is there any tool for converting .b3d to .obj file or is there any specification about .b3d model file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

introduction on b3d file format can be found here.
http://www.blitzbasic.com/sdkspecs/sdkspecs/b3dfile_specs.txt
and obj file format can be easy searched using google.

Answer (score 0):

Blender is always worth a look. It has import/export support for many formats.